# Angular 6 Connect With AWS ElasticSearch

Tags: angular, amazon-web-services, elasticsearch

I have an **elasticsearch** cluster running on **AWS**. I need to connect with elasticsearch cluster with Angular 6, what is the best way to achieve this ?. I have an access key & secret key and I have an access policy in elasticsearch that allows this user with full access. I use this below code in **NodeJs**.

```
var client = new elasticsearch.Client({
   host: process.env.ES_ENDPOINT,
   connectionClass: require('http-aws-es'),
   amazonES: {
       region: process.env.ES_REGION,
       credentials: new AWS.EnvironmentCredentials('AWS')
   },
   log: 'trace'
});
```

I want to do the same with Angular 6. I have connected without authentication like given below code:-

```
this.client = new Client({
  host: 'https://search-usercluster-xxxyuyy.ap-south-1.es.amazonaws.com/',
  log: 'trace'
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to achieve this is to use [Amazon Cognito](https://console.aws.amazon.com/cognito/home?region=us-east-1).
For example:

```
import AWS from 'aws-sdk';
AWS.config.region = 'us-east-2';
AWS.config.credentials = new AWS.CognitoIdentityCredentials({
  IdentityPoolId: 'YOUR_IDENTITY_POOL_ID'
});
const options = {
  hosts: [
    'YOUR_HOST_URL'
  ], // array of amazon es hosts (required)
  connectionClass: require('http-aws-es'), // use this connector (required)
  amazonES: AWS.config, // set an aws config e.g. for multiple clients to different regions
  log: 'trace'
};

const es = require('elasticsearch').Client(options);
```

UPD: Added import AWS from 'aws-sdk', we need to know how to get the aws.config access. Thank you @AravinthanM!

Comment: can u please provide how to import aws or aws.config?

Comment: @AravinthanM Yes! You need to use [aws-sdk](https://www.npmjs.com/package/aws-sdk)

Comment: everything was fine but i am getting this error please help me out...

Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'http-aws-es' in 'project\src\app\_services'